# Force close error expecting irregulary

Tags: java, android, android-layout, nullpointerexception

I have problem. I created an application which loads random layour from resources and I have problem because program shows random layout and closes , sometimes after 2 times and sometimes after a dozen, and I dont know where is a problem, I tried to run it on my phone and I added in the manifest write_external_storage permission, and still the same error.Please help me, and try to resolve this problem.

here is my code in :

java :

```
package ka.ka.ka;

import java.util.Random;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class KAMASActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
Button button1;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
  button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1) ;
  button1.setOnClickListener(this);

}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

       int min = 1;
        int max = 6;
        int i1=0;       
        Random r = new Random();
        i1 = r.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
        if(i1==1){setContentView(R.layout.image1);
        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1) ;
        button1.setOnClickListener(this);}
        if(i1==2){setContentView(R.layout.image2);
        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1) ;
        button1.setOnClickListener(this);}
        if(i1==3){setContentView(R.layout.image3);
        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1) ;
        button1.setOnClickListener(this);}
        if(i1==4){setContentView(R.layout.image4);
        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1) ;
        button1.setOnClickListener(this);}
        if(i1==5){setContentView(R.layout.image5);
        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1) ;
        button1.setOnClickListener(this);}
        if(i1==6){setContentView(R.layout.image6);
        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1) ;
        button1.setOnClickListener(this);
        }
        }
```

Android Manifest :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="ka.ka.ka"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_CHECKIN_PROPERTIES" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> 

  <application
    android:icon="@drawable/ikona"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".KAMASActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

And he is logcat :

```
07-10 10:58:51.062: D/ddm-heap(218): Got feature list request
07-10 10:58:51.311: D/dalvikvm(218): GC freed 506 objects / 46032 bytes in 122ms
07-10 10:59:30.081: D/AndroidRuntime(218): Shutting down VM
07-10 10:59:30.081: W/dalvikvm(218): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception     (group=0x4001b188)
07-10 10:59:30.081: E/AndroidRuntime(218): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
07-10 10:59:30.102: E/AndroidRuntime(218): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-10 10:59:30.102: E/AndroidRuntime(218):  at   ka.ka.ka.KAMASActivity.onClick(KAMASActivity.java:32)
07-10 10:59:30.102: E/AndroidRuntime(218):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2364)
07-10 10:59:30.102: E/AndroidRuntime(218):  at android.view.View.onTouchEvent(View.java:4179)
07-10 10:59:30.102: E/AndroidRuntime(218):  at  android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:6541)
07-10 10:59:30.102: E/AndroidRuntime(218):  at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3709)
07-10 10:59:30.102: E/AndroidRuntime(218):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
07-10 10:59:30.102: E/AndroidRuntime(218):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
07-10 10:59:30.102: E/AndroidRuntime(218):  at    android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
0 7-10 10:59:30.102: E/AndroidRuntime(218):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
07-10 10:59:30.102: E/AndroidRuntime(218):  at  com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow. java:1659)
07-10 10:59:30.102: E/AndroidRuntime(218):  at   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1107)
07-10 10:59:30.102: E/AndroidRuntime(218):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2061)
07-10 10:59:30.102: E/AndroidRuntime(218):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1643)
07-10 10:59:30.102: E/AndroidRuntime(218):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1691)
07-10 10:59:30.102: E/AndroidRuntime(218):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-10 10:59:30.102: E/AndroidRuntime(218):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-10 10:59:30.102: E/AndroidRuntime(218):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
07-10 10:59:30.102: E/AndroidRuntime(218):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-10 10:59:30.102: E/AndroidRuntime(218):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-10 10:59:30.102: E/AndroidRuntime(218):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
07-10 10:59:30.102: E/AndroidRuntime(218):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
07-10 10:59:30.102: E/AndroidRuntime(218):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-10 10:59:30.121: I/dalvikvm(218): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
07-10 10:59:30.121: E/dalvikvm(218): Unable to open stack trace file '/data/anr/traces.txt': Permission denied
07-10 10:59:32.562: I/Process(218): Sending signal. PID: 218 SIG: 9
```

Answer (score 0):

You're probably missing an id somewhere in your layout file which is causing one of the buttons to not be found in your on click method. If you could post your layout xml file we could tell you exactly where.

Answer (score 0):

one of the id's `R.image.imageX` are missing. They could be misspelled or you might have missed naming them,so check those.

It's also possible that you are referring to an id which is not declared in main.xml (the xml file being referred in this activity `setContentView(R.layout.main);` ).

Hope you make it work. :-)